Unable to boot Solaris from external scsi cd drive on a Sun Blade 150
I am trying to boot Solaris 8 from external scsi CD-ROM drive Yamaha 8/8/24 on a Sun blade 150 through Open Boot. Its scsi ID is set to 6.
probe-scsi-all reports that the CD drive is at: /pci@1f,0/pci@5/scsi@1 target 6, unit 0.
So I am trying to boot with this command:
boot /pci@1f,0/pci@5/scsi@1/disk@6,0
But it just halts until I switch off the external scsi CD drive. Then it fails with an error. The CD drive does not give any read indication during the entire time. The Solaris cd and the CD drive are OK I think, I only have some doubts about the scsi cable.
Is this the correct command to boot in my case?
Maybe the Yamaha is not compatible with the Sun hardware?

Did you search here for Solaris info? This seems appropriate , but I only used Solarris, I didn't have to cfg/install.

Yes. In my case I am trying to use scsi drive and not USB or IDE. I have a problem with IDE.

/pci@1f,0/pci@5/scsi@1/disk@6,0 is just the disk - IIRC you also need to specify a partition, with something like /pci@1f,0/pci@5/scsi@1/disk@6,0:a

Unix requires a 512 bytes block size configured on the SCSI CD-drive to boot, so I had to change the block size to 512 bytes by adding a  jumper to my Yamaha CRW-8824S located inside the SCSI enclosure and I booted with:
boot /pci@1f,0/pci@5/scsi@1/disk@6,0:f

where /pci@1f,0/pci@5/scsi@1 is the path to my SCSI pci card, 6 is SCSI ID set on the SCSI enclosure/drive, 0 is the unit and f should be the partition to boot from. Without "f" it complained that there was nothing to execute.
The jumper setting is on the SCSI CD-drive inside the SCSI enclosure. It can not be set from the outside, you need to open the enclosure.
